# Inconsitant mergeMap behaviour

Tags: javascript, ajax, rxjs, rxjs6

I am currently working on a file uploading method which requires me to limit the number of concurrent requests coming through.

I've begun by writing a prototype to how it should be handled

```
const items = Array.from({ length: 50 }).map((_, n) => n);
from(items)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(n => {
      return of(n).pipe(delay(2000));
    }, 5)
  )
  .subscribe(n => {
    console.log(n);
  });
```

And it did work, however as soon as I swapped out the `of` with the actual call. It only processes one chunk, so let's say 5 out of 20 files

```
from(files)
  .pipe(mergeMap(handleFile, 5))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

The `handleFile` function returns a call to my custom ajax implementation

```
import { Observable, Subscriber } from 'rxjs';
import axios from 'axios';

const { CancelToken } = axios;

class AjaxSubscriber extends Subscriber {
  constructor(destination, settings) {
    super(destination);
    this.send(settings);
  }

  send(settings) {
    const cancelToken = new CancelToken(cancel => {
      // An executor function receives a cancel function as a parameter
      this.cancel = cancel;
    });
    axios(Object.assign({ cancelToken }, settings))
      .then(resp => this.next([null, resp.data]))
      .catch(e => this.next([e, null]));
  }

  next(config) {
    this.done = true;
    const { destination } = this;
    destination.next(config);
  }

  unsubscribe() {
    if (this.cancel) {
      this.cancel();
    }
    super.unsubscribe();
  }
}

export class AjaxObservable extends Observable {
  static create(settings) {
    return new AjaxObservable(settings);
  }

  constructor(settings) {
    super();
    this.settings = settings;
  }

  _subscribe(subscriber) {
    return new AjaxSubscriber(subscriber, this.settings);
  }
}
```

So it looks something like this like

```
function handleFile() {
  return AjaxObservable.create({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
  });
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2wpr3n12vn)

If I remove the concurrency parameter from the merge map function everything works fine, but it uploads all files all at once. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Why do you use `mergeMap` ? Is there a reason why you would flatten it ? Also, how do you expect it to behave, wait until the file is uploaded then start with the next file?

Comment: Because i want the chunk of requests to be dealt in parallel. No there isn't a specific reason to flatten it, i was just flattening it to make it easier for counting how many files have gone trough. I would expect it to start 5 requests, wait till 5 of them are finished and then start another 5

Comment: The only question here's what's inside `handleFile` because `mergeMap` works the same with Observables and Promises so `handleFile` is suspicious here.

Comment: Yeah you need to add some more detail to this, i.e. what does `handleFile` do, also where are `fileCount` and `subscriber` coming from?

Comment: @martin @paulpdaniels thank you for your input. I apologise for making the question unclear, I have now updated the code to show the `handleFile` function as well as linked an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was me not calling `complete()` method inside `AjaxSubscriber`, so I modified the code to:

```
pass(response) {
  this.next(response);
  this.complete();
}
```

And from axios call:

```
axios(Object.assign({ cancelToken }, settings))
  .then(resp => this.pass([null, resp.data]))
  .catch(e => this.pass([e, null]));
```